# call static method given a class object in java

Tags: java

If

```
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] str) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}

// in some other file and method
Class klass = Class.forName("MyClass");
```

How can I call `MyClass.main`? I do not have the string "MyClass" at compile time, so I cannot simply call `MyClass.main(String[]{})`.

Comment: Reflection and class loading can do this. Can you tell us the motivation behind this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You use [reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html) to invoke methods (or create objects etc). Below is a sample to invoke `main()` method in `MyClass`. All you need to make sure is that `MyClass` is in the classpath.

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("MyClass");
Method m = cls.getMethod("main", String[].class);
String[] params = null; 
m.invoke(null, (Object) params);
```

Comment: I would NOT call a `main` entry-point method passing it a `null` argument.  The `java` launcher calls `main` with an empty array if there are no command line arguments, and most `main` methods don't bother to check for `null`.

Comment: @StephenC thanx for the info on java launcher. I didn't know that.