# How to get methods from Class.forName() in Java?

Tags: java

**EDITED**

I have an unknown class that only variable of string that called **namo** knows and it has method called **paintah** with **Graphics g** parameter. Now I am trying to do:

```
Class.forName(namo).getMethod("paintah", ??????????);
```

What do I replace the question marks with? I am trying to figure it out for hours.

Also if I use same class with the same code (but only I know it's name **Classo**) like this:

```
new Classo.paintah(g);
```

it works.

**UPDATE**
Ok so I've got two classes, one has this part of code:

```
public static Classo cla = new Classo();
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
       Class.forName(namo).getMethod("paintah", Graphics.class); //not working
       cla.paintah(g); // working
}
```

That's lets say the main class, now the **Classo** which has the same code as of the unknown class has this part of code:

```
public void paintah(Graphics g){
       g.fillRect(20,20,200,200);
}
```

So yeah, I hope that gives a better idea..

Comment: When was the last time you visited the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class...))!

Comment: What part of the documentation do you not understand?

Comment: @BrianRoach Your link didn't get encoded properly - you might want to edit it.

Comment: Are you sure you need reflection here?  Why not implement an interface?

Comment: This may not be what you're looking for but if you're just trying to access the method... new blah().paintah() works.

Comment: As has already been mentioned above, you should consult the Javadoc.

Comment: What do you mean cunsult the javadoc? I am new here, sorry

Comment: You can't program Java if you don't know how to use documentation. The Java editions come with documentation you can browse by package, class down to methods, and it'll usually answer your questions. Please consider also taht each time you say "it doesn't work" *without* saying how exactly it doesn't work you deserve -1 and even less answers to ignorant questions.

Comment: `new Classo.paintah(g);` - This doesn't make sense.  Is it `Classo.paintah(g);` calling a static method, or `new Classo().paintah(g);` calling an instance method on a newly instantiated object?

Comment: Yayaya meant to write `new Classo()....` mispelled it, but it doesn't fix the main problem

Answer (score 4):

You are using the [`getMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...)) method that takes a varargs argument of `Class` objects that represent the types of the parameters in your target method.

If it takes only a `Graphics` object, then supply `Graphics.class`:

```
Class.forName("bla").getMethod("paintah", Graphics.class);
```

Since you know the class name, you don't even need `Class.forName`, you can access it using a *class literal*.

```
bla.class.getMethod("paintah", Graphics.class);
```

Either way, you'll need to catch the `Exceptions` that are thrown from the `getMethod` call:

> Throws:
>
> NoSuchMethodException - if a matching method is not found or
> if the name is ""or "".
> NullPointerException - if name is null
> SecurityException - If a security manager, s, is present and
> any of the following conditions is met:
>
> - invocation of
>   s.checkMemberAccess(this, Member.PUBLIC) denies access to the method
> - the caller's class loader is not the same as or an ancestor of the
>   class loader for the current class and invocation of
>   s.checkPackageAccess() denies access to the package of this class

Comment: Well not really right thing to do:
this code is inside of paintComponent(graphics g) and I need to hook up with the method from another class
What I would normally do is
bla.paintah(g);

Comment: I need to recreate that but using the "forName"

Comment: something like Class.forName("bla").getMethod(paintah(g));

Comment: And no I don't know the class name, I gave an example

Comment: If you don't know the class name at compile time, but you have the name of the class at runtime, the `Class.forName` is the way to go.  I don't know why `Class.forName(namo).getMethod("paintah", Graphics.class);` wouldn't work for you.  Don't forget you still have to `invoke` the `Method` that you get back.

Comment: The thing is that I have to throw the **g** parameter in to that method, let me update my post to give more info

Comment: Pass `g` into `invoke`, not `getMethod`: `method.invoke(null, g);` if the method is `static`.  There are more exceptions to catch on `invoke`.

Comment: How exactly do I do that?

Comment: Gives me an exception: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Class.paintah(java.awt.Graphics)`

Comment: `method = Class.forName(namo).getClass().getMethod("paintah", Graphics.class);
    method.invoke(g);`

Comment: The first parameter of the `invoke` method is the instance on which to invoke the method; the rest of the parameters are the actual parameters to the method.  Try something like `method.invoke(new Classo(), g);`.

Comment: `Class.forName(namo).getMethod("paintah",Graphics.class).invoke(g);`
giving cast exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@4ef259d6

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public void MyMethod(MyParameterType param);
}
```

Then you can get method object like this:

```
Class.forName("MyClass").getMethod("MyMethod", MyParameterType.class);
```

From **getMethod()** javadoc:

```
The name parameter is a String specifying the simple name of 
the desired method. The parameterTypes parameter is an array of 
Class objects that identify the method's formal parameter types, 
in declared order. If parameterTypes is null, 
it is treated as if it were an empty array.
```

Comment: It doesn't really work, I have as you described in the first code box

Comment: But on the other class I have paintComponent(graphics g) and if I use bla.paintah(g); it works, but if I use Class.forName("bla").getMethod("paintah", Graphics.class);
It doesn't

Comment: Update in your post is a bit misleading. Do you need to just get an object  representing a method in your class? Or you also need to invoke this method? If latter - make sure to call myMethod.invoke(myParam);

Comment: hmmmmm `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Class.paintah(java.awt.Graphics)` maybe I invoked wrongly?
`method = Class.forName(namo).getClass().getMethod("paintah", Graphics.class);
    method.invoke(g);`

Comment: You should not call getClass() on Class object. Correct your code: Class.forName(name).getMethod("paintah",Graphics.class).invoke(g);

Comment: hmmm `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@48cb3966` I have to cast it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the method you need to invoke it.
There's an explanation here: [call static method given a class object in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042740/call-static-method-given-a-class-object-in-java)