# How to convert two methods with identical body into one method using generics?

Tags: java, generics

I have two following methods:

```
public class LoaderService {
    public static Config loadConfigFile() {
        try (var jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(Path.PROJECT_RESOURCES + "config" + Extension.JSON))) {
            return new Gson().fromJson(jsonReader, Config.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return Config.builder().build();
        }
    }

    public static UriContainer loadUriContainerFile() {
        try (var jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(Path.PROJECT_RESOURCES + "URI container" + Extension.JSON))) {
            return new Gson().fromJson(jsonReader, UriContainer.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return UriContainer.builder().build();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, body are identical - I can pass fileName through method parameter. The methods load the content from a JSON file. The only significant difference in their bodies is the type of class that has been applied.
I thought about something like that:

```
public class LoaderService<T> {
    public T loadFile(String fileName) {
        try (var jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            return new Gson().fromJson(jsonReader, T.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return T.builder().build();
        }
    }
```

but I got error there:

```
return T.builder().build();
// ---> Cannot resolve method 'builder' in 'T'
```

my dto - for example Config:

```
package dto;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Value;

@Value
@Builder
public class Config {
    String url;
    String username;
    String password;
    String jdbcDriverPath;
    String driverClassName;
    String hostname;
    String port;
    String serverPath;
}
```

---

Is it possible to apply generics in above situation?
**Sorry if this question doesn't make sense because I'm just learning generics**

Comment: There's not going to be a good way to generify this.  You'd have to pass in, at minimum, a `Class<T>` and a `Supplier<TBuilder>`.

Comment: no you cant, but you can do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042740/call-static-method-given-a-class-object-in-java/9042754

Comment: I edited my post, please look again - I added an error message. I will also add that these methods do not have to be static. I can give it up.

Comment: It would make more sense to use generics if you had more than only 2 different instances of this LoaderService. Otherwise you end up with increased complexity and possibility a decrease in performance for something that could otherwise be simplified as you currently have it. Here is a reference to what you need to do to use generics. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/classes.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a class as argument to a method, then calling static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65791611/passing-a-class-as-argument-to-a-method-then-calling-static-methods)

Comment: The amount of duplicated code is tiny. I wouldn’t bother and instead would spend my time building some new or better functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is impossible, because you cannot abstract the concept of a static method.

Why do you think 'FooFactory' is such a java meme? That's what factories are: Abstracting the concept of that builder method.

However, the idea of just returning a 'blank' instance if any exception occurs seems **extremely** ill-advised. There are a million-and-one reasons for that error, surely 'throw away all info about that error and return a blank instance' is a fine formula for spending literally HOURS chasing down bugs, and an app that just does bizarre things, because code keeps going and discards debug info when unexpected things happen.

Perhaps you intended to return a blank instance only in the specific scenario of that file simply not existing. In that case, I'd be catching `FileNotFoundException` instead.

### The easy solution: Stop with the crazy catch blocks

It's 100% reasonable for a method named `loadFile` to be declared as `throws IOException`. If you find that 'annoying' in the caller, remember, `public static void main` should be declared with `throws Exception` on it.

### The hard solution: Factories

You need to abstract the concept of a builder, or at least the concept of 'make me a default blank instance'.

Let's use Supplier (it's called Supplier, but we're using it as a Factory here):

```
public static <T> T loadFile(Class<T> type, Supplier<T> defaultMaker) {
  try (var jsonReader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
    return new Gson().fromJson(jsonReader, type);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // I really, really wouldn't do this, but...
    return defaultMaker.get();
  }
}
```

### Some information about generics

Why does `T.class` not work? Why does `T.builder()` not work? Because generics are figments of javac's imagination. The runtime has *no idea*. Most generics are flat out erased (they do not survive compilation), and there where it isn't, it's, as far as `java.exe` is concerned, a comment.

Thus, `T.class`? That is impossible: T is a thing at compile time, not at runtime. Javac doesn't know what T is, therefore T.class is impossible. Same argument explains why `T.builder()` cannot possibly work. Java doesn't know anything about T, at all. It could be anything. It can obviously be a type that doesn't have a `builder()` method.

Because of this, generics are best thought of as a 'linking' tool. It links things. Thus, if you use generics in only one place, it's useless or an ugly hack.

By having a `Class<T>`, a `Supplier<T>`, and as return type, `T`, you've given javac something useful to do: Javac will ensure that these things can apply to any type (T has no bounds), but that they all apply to the same type. Javac can check that you're giving a Supplier that only makes String objects, that you pass in `String.class`, and will then let you invoke `.toLowerCase()` on the result of invoking this method (and javac will generate a silent cast to make that work at runtime, given that runtime has no idea what generics is).

If you think it through, the runtime doesn't need to know what T is. That's a useful rule to remember: If your code can't work unless the runtime knows what T is, you can't do that.

### A slight upgrade: Add covariance

Generics are complicated; they are invariant by default (a subtype isn't a valid replacement for any given type; this is unlike normal types, where you can assign e.g. a String expression to a variable of type Object. Not so in generics; you can NOT assign an expression of type `List<String>` to a variable of type `List<Object>`. Instead, you declare the variance as you write your types out. In this case, it's perfectly fine if the supplier only makes subtypes, that still works. So, really, this should be: `public static <T> T loadFile(Class<T> type, Supplier<? extends T> defaultMaker) { ... }`. However, if you aren't quite following why you need to do that, that's okay. It's rather unlikely to matter and this is already complicated enough.

### Your code has another extremely nasty bug

This bug will cost you a few days, so, fix it, remember it, update your IDE to flag this.

**Do not EVER use `FileReader`.** <sup>1</sup>

The class is not fit for purpose. If your IDE has the facility to 'ban' things (mark as error if you use it), then add it.

The problem is, FileReader uses 'platform default encoding', and who knows what that might be. JSON **requires** UTF_8.

The right move is:

```
Files.newBufferedReader(filePath)
```

Instead of `new FileReader`. That's because `Files` defaults to UTF-8 instead of 'platform default'. Alternatively, `new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))`.

Note that if you are on a platform that has UTF-8 as default, it is **impossible** to test for this error, and yet, it will blow up in your face when someone runs your code on a platform that doesn't (and most platforms don't), and you try to read a JSON file with a non-ASCII character in it.

These are the kinds of bugs that cause tons of damage, because you didn't test for them so they tend to make it into production.

[1] Starting with JDK11, there is a constructor of `FileReader` that takes a charset. However, JDK11 (in fact, JDK8) has the new Files API which is a major improvement. Therefore, there is no reason to use FileReader: on obsolete JDK versions it's broken due to using platform default encoding (which is just wrong, if the aim is to treat it as JSON), and on modern JDK versions there is a better alternative. Either way, FileReader is the wrong answer.